# Массив не видно за пределами функции

Tags: javascript, node.js

Собираю данные в массив из MongoDB:

```
  let part = []
  const crosses = []
  codes.forEach(async c => {
    part = await Crosses.find({
      $or: [{
        number1: c.code,
        brand1: c.brand
      }, {
        number2: c.code,
        brand2: c.brand
      }]
    })
    for (let i = 0; i < part.length; i++) {
      crosses.push(part[i])
    }
  })
```

После этой функции forEach массив crosses пуст, но если я делаю console.log(crosses) сразу после цикла for, там есть данные - то есть, все работает как надо. Как вытащить этот массив наружу функции?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Операции то у вас асинхронные, все это дело лучше обернуть в `Promise.all`:

```
const crosses = [];

await Promise.all(codes.map(async (code) => {
    part = await Crosses.find({
        $or: [{
            number1: c.code,
            brand1: c.brand
        }, {
            number2: c.code,
            brand2: c.brand
        }]
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < part.length; i++) {
        crosses.push(part[i])
    }
}));

console.log(crosses);
```

Или без `await`:

```
const crosses = [];

Promise.all(codes.map(async (code) => {
    part = await Crosses.find({
        $or: [{
            number1: c.code,
            brand1: c.brand
        }, {
            number2: c.code,
            brand2: c.brand
        }]
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < part.length; i++) {
        crosses.push(part[i])
    }
})).then(() => {
    console.log(crosses);
});
```